# Popover on a Popover issue while tap on notification(Deeplink)

Tags: ios, swift, presentmodalviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller, uiview-hierarchy

I have already presented a controller on the screen and now click on the home button. Then I need to present another controller on that after tapping on notification using deeplink.
When app comes to foreground, new controller is nor presented and previous controller is also dismissed.
Getting below Warning as well:-

```
Attempt to present <NewController> on <PreviousController> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

I am using below code to present.

```
controller.transitioningDelegate = myDelegateForTransition
        controller.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
        controller.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true
viewControllerFromPresent.present(controller, animated: true, completion: {
            completionHandler?()
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by changing controller.modalPresentationStyle from custom to overCurrentContext.

```
controller.transitioningDelegate = myDelegateForTransition
    controller.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    controller.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true
viewControllerFromPresent.present(controller, animated: true, completion: {
        completionHandler?()
    })
```